# SharePoint 'My Settings' Extra fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, wss

In the top right corner of a SharePoint site the user can select "My Settings" to update their details etc.

I am currently writing an automated app that will update user profiles from an Export we are getting on a nightly basis.

My question is...can i add extra fields to the information that is stored and editable against each user?

For example if I might want to add an "Office Location" field?

I am using WSS 3.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the user list with additional column as you would any other list. When in your settings page click on the People and Groups links in the breadcrumbs. There select List Settings from the Settings menu